# Using regex to find strings between other strings and up until newline

Tags: regex

Here's some sample text that I'm working with:

```
Nmap scan report for XYZ\n

blah blah blah\n
blah blah blah\n
blah blah blah\n
data: here\n\n
```

How do I capture everything from (and including) `Nmap scan` all the way up to line containing `data` up until the end of that line? The text after `data` changes so I need to scan up until `data` and throughout the remainder of that line.

I have tried:

```
.scan(/Nmap scan.*?data.*?/m)[1]
```

but this captures everything from `Nmap scan` up until the word `data`. I thought `.*?` after the word `data` would mean capture everything after that line as well. No luck.

Also tried `(?ms)^Nmap.*?\ndata:[^\n]*` but no luck, as shown below:

```
2.5.1 :192 > puts evidence.scan(/(?ms)^Nmap.*?\ndata:[^\n]*/)
Traceback (most recent call last):
SyntaxError ((irb):192: undefined group option: /(?ms)^Nmap.*?\ndata:[^\n]*/)
```

Comment: Updated post to reflect the results of that attempt. @anubhava

Comment: I got rid of the beginning of that and this seemed to have done the trick: `evidence.scan(/Nmap.*?data:[^\n\n]*/m)`

Comment: What is your regex platform? May be `(?ms)` doesn't work. Try: `/Nmap.*?\ndata:[^\n]*/ms`

Comment: `[^\n\n]*` should be replaced with just `[^\n]*` as there is no use of repeating a character inside a character class i.e. `[...]`

Comment: Gotcha. Thanks so much. I'm using Ruby

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Converting my comment to answer so that solution is easy to find for future visitors.

In Ruby you may use this:

```
/Nmap.*?\ndata:[^\n]*/m
```

[Ruby RegEx Demo](https://rubular.com/r/UgefaGo91rvAum)

`m` enables regex engine to match new line with dot in Ruby which is usually called DOTALL in other regex flavors.

Answer (score 0):

You did not specify what language you were using. This is JavaScript notation but would easily translate to almost any regex engine:

```
/^Nmap.*?^data:.*?$/ms
```

[See RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/l4yHmG/1/)

1. '^' Matches start of the string or start of a line.
2. `Nmap` Matches "Nmap".
3. `.?*` Minimally matches any character (including newline) until the next match.
4. `data:` Matches "data:".
5. `.?*` Minimally matches any character until the next match.
6. `$` Matches the end of string or the end of line.

My assumptions is that `Nmap` and `data:` are supposed to begin at the start of a line and thus the added checks.